# Do I need to take creatine and L-glutamine on rest days to maintain a load?

Tags: creatine, supplements, recovery, l-glutamine

I use creatine and L-glutamine for my workouts, typically taking the L-glutamine about an hour before my workout, and creatine immediately after. (I don't take them together because I understand they compete for receptors, limiting absorption).

I also try to keep the load up by taking creatine first thing in the morning, and L-glutamine last thing before bed regardless of whether I worked out that day.

My question is: do I need to take these supplements on rest days in order to maintain my "load"? Should I be taking two servings* of each on rest days instead of just one? Are the daily servings unnecessary?

*A serving for me is typically a heaping spoonful dissolved in water or cold tea (I know that a sugary drink would help absorption, but I'm not willing to take the downside of the sugar).

Comment: Regarding the sugar.  I usually put about 4-8 ounces of milk or OJ in my supplements/water mixture.  You're still getting some sugar to help absorption, but at least it's not in the form of some sort of sugar water.

Comment: @PMV I'm on board with the milk, that's a good idea. I don't agree with OJ because 1. fructose and 2. it's frequently recommended not to mix creatine with citrus b/c it can convert it into creatinine which is useless (not sure of the chemical reaction that is supposedly behind this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be taking your supplements daily to maintain your load. Both of those supplements do good things not only for workouts, but for your body in general, including the brain. I would suggest continuing to take them in the same manner that you take them on "on" days.

However, most people I've come into contact with suggest taking creatine and L-glutamine twice a day, once being before bed or mid evening and once either in the morning or prior to/following your workout. When and how you take your supplements really depends on how your body reacts to them.

I'm with you on the sugar... why they have to add so much sugar to our food these days I'll never know.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I'm all for more of it, if it will really help. Just don't want to waste $ if there is no value to it.

Comment: @Greg - as far as more, taking it on the off days will be more, but as a general rule people who take it multiple times daily take less at a time. The "optimum" amount of creatine is normally listed as 0.15g per pound of body weight for loading and 0.015g per pound for maintenance. Much more than that and your body just starts flushing it, adding stress to your body's natural cleaning systems.

Comment: Are those numbers per day? i.e. if taking twice a day, split those amounts?  Any optimal amount of glutamine recommended?  Also, any additional benefit from not taking the two together (i.e. as Greg suggests in his question)?

Comment: @dolan - those numbers are per day, so yes, split them if you're going to take it more than once per day. For L-Glutamine, you should be taking 10-15 grams per day, and it is usually suggested to divide that up and take 2-3 smaller doses instead.

Comment: @Greg, I would advise you are wasting your money with L-Glutamine. I myself have taken this supplement and note that in my opinion it is a waste of money. read up for yourself here: http://examine.com/supplements/Glutamine/. thanks, James